# What is the relationship between a gravitational wave and a graviton?

Tags: quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, carrier-particles

Gravitational waves were theorized a century ago and recently discovered, leading to the awarding of the 2017 Nobel Prize in Physics. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave):

> Gravitational waves transport energy as gravitational radiation, a
>   form of radiant energy similar to electromagnetic radiation.

The comparison to electromagnetic radiation makes me think that gravitational waves must be describable in [particle terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality) as well. It also makes me think that the particle form must be the long-rumored [graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton). Yet, about the graviton, Wikipedia has to say:

> the graviton is a hypothetical elementary particle

I understand that relativity and quantum mechanics are not well integrated, and that this gravitational wave is a macro-scale phenomenon that, experimentally, doesn't have much to do with particles. But I have basically no understanding of how gravity is interpreted in quantum mechanics (it seems like you can ignore it at such small scales).

Shouldn't the detection of a gravitational wave be evidence in favor of the existence of its corresponding particle? Can gravitational waves be used to 'prove' the existence of the graviton particle?

Comment: Gravity waves are detected only from very large cosmic occurrences.  They are non-detectable on a small scale.

Answer (score 1):

The relation is the same as the one between a electromagnetic wave and a photon. And it is not true that one can ignore gravity at small distances. In fact, at very small distances of the order of the Planck length ($\sim10^{-35}\,$m), gravity becomes very strong. The Planck length is given by the square root of Newton's constant.

Comment: Dear marmot, you mean 10^-35m and do you have a link where you read this?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei Yes, I meant to write $10^{-35} m$, which corresponds to $\sim 1/(10^{18}\text{GeV})$, i.e. $1/M_\text{P}$.