# Why matter is transparent to gravitational waves?

Tags: gravitational-waves, matter

I recently asked a question at Astronomy.SE related to matter-gravitational waves interactions: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43265

From related question [Do gravitational waves disperse/refract (like EM waves in a prism)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/490866)

> There is also the fact that matter is transparent to gravitational waves of any frequency.

As the question does not seem to provide any references to this, this raises a few questions: What is the reason for this? Is there any specific research paper or theory that describes why this is?

Comment: Also of interest: [Do gravitational waves slow down as they pass through matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/do-gravitational-waves-slow-down-as-they-pass-through-matter)

Answer (score 6):

They interact weakly with matter - so it's not completely transparent to them.

To steal from an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/504103/295029:) to another question.

"In a 1969 paper, [Seismic Response of the Earth to a Gravitational Wave in the 1-Hz Band](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1969ApJ...156..529D), Dyson estimated that the Earth absorbs about  $10^{-21}$ of the energy of a 1-Hz gravitational wave passing through it, and that this ratio varies as the inverse square of the frequency. LIGO detects gravitational waves with frequencies of order 100 Hz, so for them the absorption ratio would be of order $10^{-25}$." ~ G. Smith

Comment: `+1` Somewhat related are answers to [Transfer of energy from gravity back to other “more familiar” forms of energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/262926/83380) ("beads on a string") and [Do gravitational waves impart linear momentum to objects? (e.g. Quasar 3C 186)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321166) ("very small") but your links are excellent!